# NSTimeInterval from text input

Tags: nsstring, avaudioplayer, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I got a question for anyone with a spare moment and an answer...

I need to change an NSString value to input into the AVAudioPlayer start offset

eg. player.currentTime = 0;   I want to change the '0' to a readable value or an NSString to a numeral value.....

Answer (score 0):

NSString has a `integerValue` function. You can also create an NSString using it's `format` class function and pass it a format string like this: `"%d"` and then your `player.currentTime`.

---

```
int timeInput = [[textField text] integerValue];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", timeInput];
```

Comment: So would it be player.currentTime = "%d"...i've got a UIText input i want to type in , lets say 240, and for the audio to play at 4 minutes in.

Comment: '- (IBAction)markCue:(id)sender; {
 
 self.cuePoint = currentTime.text;
 
 NSString *cuePointString = cuePoint;
 
  NSString *cueTime = [[NSString alloc] 
        initWithFormat:@"%d", cuePointString];
 label.text = cueTime;
 [cueTime release];
}
-(void)cuePlaybackForPlayer:(AVAudioPlayer*)p
{
 [p play];
 player.currentTime = 0;
 [self updateViewForPlayerState:p];
}'

Comment: I added two pieces of code to my answer that should help you out.

Comment: i'm sure i'm looking at this all wrong...it seems to me all the methods are already in my code i'm just not sure how to call them..Do you know what the definition or name of the '0' in 'player.currentTime = 0;'.I just need to know what variables I can replace this '0' with....I'm new to this and i cant find any tutorials on this subject...Thnx!

Comment: Looking at NSTimeInterval's definition, it's a double. Which means you will be need to set it to 0.0 and call doubleValue instead of integerValue to get it from your UITextField.

Comment: i'm confusing it....do you know of any other way i can mark a currentTime playhead position during playback using UIButton_1 to be called when i hit UIButton_2...any sample code you've seen or examples you can give...Would be hugely appreciated...--------------------------(void) markCuePointForPlayer :(AVAudioPlayer*)p  {'need Method'}----------------------------------(void) cuePlaybackForPlayer: (AVAudioPlayer *)p    { [p play]   player.currentTime = --method value--}    THANKS!!!!!!!

Comment: Let's have a chat about exactly what you're doing on stackoverflow chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3585/objective-c-public